# automated scrolling video playback

Tags: javascript, video, drupal-6, playback

I would like to add an automatically scrolling sidebar to go through my videos and play them back (like this: http://video.on.nytimes.com/). I'm guessing I will need to create some highly customized javascript. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to accomplish this. I'm using drupal 6 and building a custom block module to do this. Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

That's easy...

the css

```
#videolist_container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.videoitem {
  height: 75px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

the html

```
<div id="videolist_container">
  <div id="videolist">

    <div class="videoitem">
      video 1 - description+photo+link
    </div>

    <div class="videoitem">
      video 2 - description+photo+link
    </div>

    <div class="videoitem">
      video 3 - description+photo+link
    </div>

    (...)

    <div class="videoitem">
      video N - description+photo+link
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, I see that's the CSS...but I guess I'll need some javascript in order to get it to automatically scroll to the next video and begin to play...or is this flash?